# Auto complete geocoding with PTV Developer

Tags: ptv-developer

I was asked to implement an auto-complete geocoding with PTV Developer. I Know that the alternative xLocate 2 geocoder offers some async approach where a new geocoding call is created for each typed/deleted character.

Does anyone have such a sample for PTV Developer's Geocoding and Places API?

Thanks, B.

PS here's the showcase based on xLocate2
https://xserver2-europe-eu-test.cloud.ptvgroup.com/dashboard/Default.htm#Showcases/Geocoding/Basic/index.htm%3FTocPath%3DShowcases%7CGeocoding%7C_____1

Answer (score 0):

you can implement an autocomplete geocoding with the PTV Developer the same way as with the xLocate2.

To implement a basic autocomplete with JavaScript have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp.

Get your free APIKey for the PTV Developer on https://developer.myptv.com/. A quick start on how to use the Geocoding and Places API can be found in the documentation: https://developer.myptv.com/Documentation/Geocoding%20API/QuickStart.htm

Below you find a test snippet with the implementation of an autocomplete geocoding using the PTV Developer Geocoding and Places API.

```js
// Check out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

$(document).ready(function() {

  // declare endpoint and feature to be used
  var geoEndpoint = "https://api.myptv.com/geocoding/v1/locations/by-text";

  // create url for fetch
  var geoURL = new URL(geoEndpoint);

  // get your free API Key for the PTV Developer here: https://developer.myptv.com/
  var apiKey = "<Enter your APIKey here>";


  geoAutocomplete($("#input_singlefieldSearch"));

  // address string
  var strInput = "";

  // bind event to #geocodingInput
  $("#input_singlefieldSearch").bind("enterKey", function(e) {
    // read input value
    strInput = $("#input_singlefieldSearch").val();
    console.log(strInput);

    // request query
    var requestQuery = {
      searchText: strInput,
      apiKey: apiKey,
      //countryFilter: "DE",
      language: "en",
    };

    // append request query to url
    geoURL.search = new URLSearchParams(requestQuery).toString();

    console.log(geoURL);

    // fetch json stream
    fetch(geoURL)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // call findAddress method
        findAddress(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });

  // trigger event on enterkey in #geocodingInput
  $("#input_singlefieldSearch").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
  });

  // Set marker and fly to position on map
  function findAddress(response) {
    console.log(response);
    // select first result of request
    var coordinates = [
      response.locations[0].referencePosition.latitude,
      response.locations[0].referencePosition.longitude,
    ];
    // place marker at location
    // L.marker(coordinates).addTo(map);
    // fly to location on map
    // map.flyTo(coordinates, 14);
  }

  // autocomplete function takes a text field element as an argument
  function geoAutocomplete(inp) {
    var currentFocus;

    // URL for the locations by text search
    var locationsByTextURL = new URL(geoEndpoint);

    inp.on("input", function() {
      var list,
        item,
        requestQuery,
        val = this.value;

      /* close any already open lists of autocompleted values */
      closeAllLists();

      // don't do anything when no input
      if (!val) {
        return false;
      }

      currentFocus = -1;

      /* create a DIV element that will contain the items (values): */
      list = document.createElement("DIV");
      list.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      list.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

      /* append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container: */
      this.parentNode.appendChild(list);

      // request query
      var requestQuery = {
        searchText: val,
        //countryFilter: "DE",
        language: "en",
      };

      // append request query to url
      locationsByTextURL.search = new URLSearchParams(requestQuery).toString();

      // fetch json stream
      fetch(locationsByTextURL, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            apiKey: apiKey,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          // for each returned location
          for (i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {
            /* create a DIV element for each matching element: */
            item = document.createElement("DIV");

            item.innerHTML = data.locations[i].formattedAddress;

            item.innerHTML +=
              "<input type='hidden' value='" +
              data.locations[i].formattedAddress +
              "'>";

            /* execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element): */
            item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp[0].value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                    (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
            });

            list.appendChild(item);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });

    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.on("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
            increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
            decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
    });

    function addActive(x) {
      /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
      if (!x) return false;
      /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
      removeActive(x);
      if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = x.length - 1;
      /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
      x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }

    function removeActive(x) {
      /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
      }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
      /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
        except the one passed as an argument:*/
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
          x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    /* execute a function when someone clicks in the document: */
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* Autocomplete input field */

.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 1px;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-group mb-3 autocomplete">
    <p> Geocoding mit dem PTV Developer. Get your free APIKey on <a href="https://developer.myptv.com/">https://developer.myptv.com/</a> </p>
    <!--Make sure the input field has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
    <input id="input_singlefieldSearch" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" size="25" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter address" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```